# Detection of methods without a summary with Regular Expression

Tags: regex

Is there a regular expression that matches methods without a summary?

```
/// <summary>
/// Test
/// </summary> 
private void SampleOne()
{

}

///<summary>
/// Test
///</summary>
private void SampleTwo(string testParameter)
{
   
}


private void WithOutSummaryBlocks()
{
   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for support, i solved this problem. Below is the Regex statement and an example usage.

Regex:

```
(|>|)+\\s*s*\\b(public|private|internal|protected|void)\\s*s*\\b(async)?\\s*\\b(static|virtual|abstract|void)?\\s*\\b(async)?\\b(Task)?\\s*[A-Za-z_0-9]*(?<method>\\s[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*\\s*)\\((([a-zA-Z\\[\\]\\<\\>]*\\s*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*\\s*)[,]?\\s*)+\\)
```

C# Usage Case:

```
try {
  string regex = @"(|>|)+\\s*s*\\b(public|private|internal|protected|void)\\s*s*\\b(async)?\\s*\\b(static|virtual|abstract|void)?\\s*\\b(async)?\\b(Task)?\\s*[A-Za-z_0-9]*(?<method>\\s[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*\\s*)\\((([a-zA-Z\\[\\]\\<\\>]*\\s*[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*\\s*)[,]?\\s*)+\\)";
  string allTextFromFile = "YOUR SOURCE CODE";
  MatchCollection matchedMethods = Regex.Matches(allTextFromFile, regex,
    RegexOptions.Singleline, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

  foreach(Match methodText in matchedMethods) {
    if (!methodText.Value.Contains(">")) {
      //This method also does not have summary blocks. 
      Console.WriteLine($"Method Name {methodText.Groups.LastOrDefault().Value}");
    }
  }
} catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException timeoutException) {
  Console.WriteLine("skipped regex");
}
```